# JQuery resizeable cancel is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery Ui resizeable [JQueryUI resizeable](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) to resize a DIV, i want to prevent the resize for some child elements inside the DIV. There is a option `cancel` to do it, but its not working to me

```
<div id="resize" class="demodiv">Resize me!
    <div class="cancel">
        HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#resize').resizable({
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
    cancel:".cancel",
});
```

Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfqtt/32/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the intention of the `cancel` option is to prevent elements resizing which are selected by the original selector (`#resize`) but not in the cancel selector (`.cancel`). It does not apply to child elements of the target resizable.

For example:

#### html

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box no-resize"></div>
```

#### js

```
$(".box").resizable({
    cancel: ".no-resize"
});
```